# How to make TextToSpeech speak even louder?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, talkback

I'm developing an app to guide visually impaired users, and use Android `TextToSpeech` to read messages. My app is used on the streets, where there can ba lots of noises and my app needs to speak REALLY loud to ensure the users can hear it clearly. The problem is, I already tried to use `AudioManager` to set the stream volume (I'm using `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`) to the max, but still the result is somewhat unsatisfying. Is there anyway that I can perhaps process the audio stream to make it even louder before playing it?

And how about TalkBack? Is it possible to do similar things with it?

Comment: On Android there's `TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile()`, so in theory you could write the speech as audio to a file, process the file and play back the processed file. Maybe the volume can be increased without distortion, maybe not. And all this might add some delay before the processed audio is played back.

Comment: I don't think I can afford much delay (say no more than 50ms) though, as the app is suppose to deliver real-time messages to the users.